# Stripe card details auto fill not wokring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am using stripe for the pyament methods but unable to pre fill the fields although I am providing the payment_method_ID in the intent being created.

```
//Creating customer if does not exist 
customer = await stripe.customers.create({
                        email : user.email || null,
                        description : 'Helpaas Offer',
                        name : user.name || null
                    });
//Creating Payment Intent

const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
                    amount: amount || 100,
                    currency: "Eur",
                    customer : 'cus_L89XOh7b8Z3aCt',
                    payment_method : 'card_1KTnI8Hbhjmc0b01rYAY7YfC', // for now static
                    automatic_payment_methods: {
                        enabled: true,
                      },
                });
                resolve({clientSecret:  paymentIntent }) // sending back to FrontEnd
```

This is how I am handling the Payment Intent in my Reactjs.

```
{ cartDetails && cartDetails.length > 0 && Object.values(clientSecret).length > 0 ?
                        <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={{'clientSecret' : clientSecret}}>
                            <InjectedCheckoutForm items={cartDetails} />
                        </Elements> : ''
                      }
```

Here is my  Component.

```
export default function InjectedCheckoutForm(props) {
const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState(false);
const [error, setError] = useState(null);
const [processing, setProcessing] = useState(false);
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
const [saveCard, setSaveCard] = useState(false)
const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState('');
const stripe = useStripe();
const elements = useElements();

const [appearance,SetAppearance] = useState({theme: 'night'}) 


useEffect(()=>{

  if (!stripe) {
    return;
  }
  // Retrieve the "payment_intent_client_secret" query parameter appended to
  // your return_url by Stripe.js
  const clientSecret = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
    'payment_intent_client_secret'
  );

  // Retrieve the PaymentIntent
  if(clientSecret){
    setProcessing(true)
    stripe
    .retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret)
    .then(({paymentIntent}) => {
      // Inspect the PaymentIntent `status` to indicate the status of the payment
      // to your customer.
      //
      // Some payment methods will [immediately succeed or fail][0] upon
      // confirmation, while others will first enter a `processing` state.
      //
      // [0]: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods#payment-notification
      // alert(paymentIntent.status);
      console.log(paymentIntent,"CHEKC T?E PAYMENT INTENT RECIEVED...")
      switch (paymentIntent.status) {
        case 'succeeded':
          saveOrder(paymentIntent,props['items']);
          break;
        case 'processing':
          toastr.info("Payment processing..." ,"We'll update you when payment is received.");
          window.history.pushState({},'','/order');
          window.location.reload();
          break;

        case 'requires_payment_method':
          // Redirect your user back to your payment page to attempt collecting
          // payment again
          toastr.error('Payment failed.','Please try another payment method.');
          break;

        default:
          toastr.error('','Something went wrong.');
          break;
      }
    });
  }
  
},[stripe]);

const saveOrder = async (paymentIntent,orderDetails)=>{
  if (paymentIntent['status'] === "succeeded" || paymentIntent['status'] === "pending") {
    // save the order in the database
    orderService.saveOrder({
      ClientID: store.get('userDetails')?.ClientID,
      OrderDetails: orderDetails,
      PaymentDetails: paymentIntent,
      status : paymentIntent['status'],
      OfferID : orderDetails[0].OfferID,
      PriceTotal : paymentIntent['amount'],
      OrderedBy : store.get('userDetails').displayName,
      Buyer : store.get('userDetails').mail,
      Seller : orderDetails[0].DisplayName ,
      ItemDetails : orderDetails,
      StripePaymentMethod : paymentIntent['payment_method'],
      Quantity : orderDetails.length || 1,
      stripePaymentID : paymentIntent['id']

    })
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(response => {
        if (response['statusCode'] === 200) {
          toastr.success('Thank You!', 'Your order has been successfull.Please check your orders.');
          window.history.pushState({},'','/order');
          window.location.reload();
        }
      })
  } else {
    toastr.error('',this.props?.t(`GenericMessage.Error`))
  }
  setProcessing(false)
}
const handleChange = async (event) => {
  // Listen for changes in the CardElement
  // and display any errors as the customer types their card details
  setDisabled(event.empty);
  setError(event.error ? event.error.message : "");
};

const saveCardForFuture = async (ev,{checked,value})=>{
  console.log(checked,value);
  setSaveCard(checked)
}
const handleSubmit = async ev => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  setProcessing(true);
  if (!stripe || !elements) {
    // Stripe.js has not yet loaded.
    // Make sure to disable form submission until Stripe.js has loaded.
    return;
  }

  const {error} = await stripe.confirmPayment({
    //`Elements` instance that was used to create the Payment Element
    elements,
    confirmParams: {
      return_url: 'http://localhost:3050/ordersummary?cartITems=1',
    },
  });
  
};
return (
  <form id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    {stripe && <PaymentElement />}
      {elements &&
        <Checkbox label="Save card for Future payments." checked={saveCard} onChange={saveCardForFuture}/>
      }
      <Button type='submit' disabled={!stripe} size='small' style={{marginTop: '15px'}} className='full-width'>Pay with Card</Button>

  </form>
);
}
type propTypes = {
  items :any
}
```

Basically I want to provide end-user a way to prefill the information in the PaymentElement of Stripe except the mandatory thing i.e CVV. I tried with the Stripe support but as per them passing just the *customerID* to the payment intent will work and stripe will automatically handle all things. But When Card Elements are rendering the customer details are not coming auto filled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fields of any Elements component (including Payment Element) **cannot** be prefilled. If you already have a Payment Method object (`pm_xxx`), then you'd simply pass that to the the relevant Stripe.js function to confirm (i.e. [`confirmCardPayment`](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment#stripe_confirm_card_payment-existing)). This does not work with the Payment Element however, which requires an Elements instance by passed.

Comment: hey Jonathan, what about this video? Prefill cards on Checkout https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrqSXUzW7_w

Is it related to stripe checkout session, but not to payment intent?

Comment: Yep, Checkout can pre-fill payment methods as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout#handling-existing-customers). It's just not possible with Elements.

Comment: then whats the use case of on-session saved cards?

Comment: If they're setup/saved for future on-session usage, then Stripe can request SCA exemptions for those cases which will bypass any auth/3DS requirements (i.e. prevent customers having to complete 3DS for each subsequent payment using that card).